# using custom message for multiple intboxes in zk

Tags: customvalidator, zk

i have several intboxes under the same window parent. I created a custom validator with custom message for an intbox. For displaying the error message i use a label which i give a unique id. Now i need to use the same constraint for all the intboxes. As in the custom error message i have a unique label id  for displaying the error so how do i use the same message for all the intboxes?
Here is the code for my custom validator with custom message:

`<zscipt> <![CDATA[
        class MyConst implements Constraint, CustomConstraint {
            //Constraint//
            public void validate(Component comp, Object value) {
                if (value == null || ((Integer)value).intValue() >8)
                    throw new WrongValueException(comp, "values only b/w 0 and 8");
            }
            //CustomConstraint//
            public void showCustomError(Component comp, WrongValueException ex) {
                errmsg.setValue(ex != null ? ex.getMessage(): "");
            }
        }
        Constraint ctt = new MyConst();
    ]]>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple solutions. First, you could enhance MyConst's constructor to accept Label.

Second, you could use a name pattern. For example, if the label's ID is always a catenation of the textbox's ID and, say, "Error". Then, you could use comp.getFellow(comp.getId()+"Error") to retrieve the label.

In addition, you could use [the server-side component selector](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/January/Envisage_ZK_6%3a_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC) to get the label.